# Multiple get methods one from query variable. other without variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have question. I have two methods in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCompetitors()
{
    var competitors = _competitorRepository.GetAll().ToList();
    return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<CompetitorDTO>>(competitors));
}
```

and I have second method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetFestivalByPrice([FromQuery] int godina)
{
    if (godina <= 1800 || godina > 2020)
    {
       return BadRequest("godina must between 1800 and 2020");
    }
    var competitors = _competitorRepository.GetAllByBirth(godina);
    if (competitors == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<CompetitorDTO>>(competitors));
}
```

First one should have route api/controllername, and second one api/controllername?godina={somevalue}. I get error with this code, two methods with same path. Routes must be same, just one with parameter and other without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this

```
[NonAction]  
public IActionResult GetCompetitors()
{
    var competitors = _competitorRepository.GetAll().ToList();
    return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<CompetitorDTO>>(competitors));
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetFestivalByPrice([FromQuery] int? godina)
{
    if (godina==null) return  GetCompetitors();
    ... your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you cannot have two methods with the same path.

You can resolve this by adding an optional on your first method and combine their logic.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCompetitors([FromQuery] int? godina)
```